# Generate PDF file with external CSS iTextPdf 7

Tags: java, html, css, itext, itext7

I am new to iText 7 and trying to convert HTML page with external CSS file. The code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/pdf/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getPDF(@PathVariable Long id,
                                HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    Visit visit = visitService.getById(id);
    List<Service> services = serviceService.getServicesByVisit(visit);

    WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext);
    context.setVariable("visitEntity", visit);
    context.setVariable("services", services);
    String orderHtml = templateEngine.process("invoice", context);

    ByteArrayOutputStream target = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    converterProperties.setBaseUri("http://localhost:8080");

    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(orderHtml, target, converterProperties);

    byte[] bytes = target.toByteArray();

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=invoice.pdf")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
            .body(bytes);

}
```

The PDF file is generated correctly with the external CSS style, but I also get some exceptions that do not stop the application.

> **The exceptions are:** java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported
> pseudo css selector: :-moz-placeholder **and**
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported pseudo css selector:
> :-ms-input-placeholder

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As a general rule, please post code in a code block rather than as an image. Like this we can copy/paste easily if needed ✌️

Comment: I will have it in mind

Comment: Can you please *replace* the screenshots with actual code? Nobody will bother to look at your question until you have done that. Not because they don't want to help, on the contrary. But you have to make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

These exceptions are generated by iText's CSS parser when it encounters a pseudo-class or pseudo-element that it does not (yet) support. They are simply logged (if you have a logger configured), and the selector and its declarations are ignored.

If your output is correct, you can ignore these log messages (or remove the selectors from your CSS input).

About the selectors you mention:

Those are vendor specific selectors, indicated by the `-prefix-`: `-moz-` is the prefix for Mozilla (Firefox), `-ms-` for Microsoft (IE and Edge). Vendors use these for experimental or non-standard CSS features. It's unlikely that iText will ever support them.